# Altering table in plsql using cursor

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, cursor

How can I add a new column into an existing table using cursor?

For example what will be the answer to the question given below?

**write a cursor program to increment salary by 5% who are working in department 20. and also insert the updated salary into a new coloumn called new_sal**

I'm having problem with the second part.

Comment: Show us the code you've written, i.e. for the first part.

Comment: "cursor program" ?

Answer (score 0):

That would be dynamic SQL, as you can't *normally* perform DDL in PL/SQL. Something like this:

```
begin
  execute immediate 'alter table your_table add new_sal number';
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the changes made in table structure via execute immediate are not available for direct sql statements within same plsql block. i.e below block will not work as the update statement will not find column new_sal.

```
BEGIN
  EXECUTE immediate 'alter table tab_name add new_sal number';
  UPDATE tab_name SET new_sal = salary + (salary * 0.05) ;
END;
```

Correct way to do it is below

```
BEGIN
  EXECUTE immediate 'alter table tab_name add new_sal number';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE tab_name SET new_sal = salary + (salary * 0.05)' ;
END;
```